# Geometry of landscape page by "typearea"

Tags: koma-script, geometry, landscape, layout, typearea

I insert some `landscape pages` in my article with the package `typearea`. Then I find that the `text body` at landscape pages are two small, too much horizontal margin spaces are wasted. Please see the attached figure.

So how to enlarge the text body(width and height) at landscpe pages? And how to adjust all sizes of page(`headheight`, `bottom`, `top`, `hmargin` etc.) respectively

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{geometry,layout}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
\section{This is my Portrait Page}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\section{This is my Landscape Page}
Text in my landscape section\footnote{Footnote in Landscape}
\clearpage
Text in my landscape
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\section{This is again Portrait Page}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion without package `geometry`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{showframe}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \storeareas\normalpapersize
}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\cleardoublepage}

\newcommand*\uselandscape{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}%
  \recalctypearea
  \areaset{1.6\textwidth}{1.6\textheight}% adjust here: \areaset{<text body width>}{<text body height>}
}

\begin{document}
\section{This is my Portrait Page}

\uselandscape
\section{This is my Landscape Page}
Text in my landscape section\footnote{Footnote in Landscape}
\clearpage
Text in my landscape

\normalpapersize
\section{This is again Portrait Page}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Suggestion using package `geometry` to adjust the margins:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand*\useportrait{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{hmargin=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=4cm}%
}
\newcommand*\uselandscape{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{vmargin=2cm,left=4cm,right=3cm}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\useportrait}
\begin{document}
\section{This is my Portrait Page}

\uselandscape
\section{This is my Landscape Page}
Text in my landscape section\footnote{Footnote in Landscape}
\clearpage
Text in my landscape

\useportrait
\section{This is again Portrait Page}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! And I don't quite understand \storeareas\normalpapersize in the version of `with geometry`. They just appear one time. Is it mandatory? What's the function?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have corrected it now to `\AtBeginDocument{\useportrait}`.

Comment: @esdd this is great and really solves my issue. Is there anyway to change the margin area specific borders in areaset? So a unique margin for bottom, top gith etc.,

Comment: @esdd Would it also be possible with the `typearea` method to adjust the distance between the body text and the header?

Comment: @PLY You can change `headsep` using package `geometry`.